# How to size SVG in HTML

Tags: html, svg

I have an SVG and I want it to take up the whole screen, BUT I a non-SVG html header at the top of a fixed size, say 100 pixels. Currently, my SVG object is created with this kind of tag:

```
<svg id="svgMainCanvas" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
      xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="100%" height="100%">
```

This causes a scroll bar to appear. Is there any way to set the SVG height to be the window height minus a certain number of pixels?

Comment: This has been asked countless times already; mostly simply about arbitrary "elements" or just "divs", and not SVG specifically - but the same answers/solutions apply.

Comment: What kind of scrollbar? Vertical? Horizontal?

Comment: The scrollbar is vertical.

Answer (score 0):

## Use CSS

```
html,body{
width:100%;
height:100%;
}
#svgMainCanvas{
position:fixed; // avoid scrollbars
left:0;
top:0;
width:100%;
height:100%;
}
```